# How to display Google Calendar / FullCalendar events as links

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Is there a way in Google Calendars to make an event a clickable link, especially for display in a FullCalendar?

If not, is there a way to make an event in FullCalendar that is pulled in from Google Calendar a clickable link?

Essentially, I need each of our events that are being pulled in from Google Calendars and being displayed in FullCalendar to be a link to different page. Is there no easy way to do this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `URL` attribute of the event object to any url you want. Alternatively you can intercept the event object before render using the `eventRender` callback and edit the `url` attribute then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you provide an example of both of these?